# Android : Adding Notes to Existing Contacts

Tags: android, contactscontract

I'm trying to use the ContactsContract api to add some notes to my contacts. I'm not sure I fully understand the various contact IDs and Raw Contact IDs. My problem seems pretty similar to what is discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3100506/add-datas-phone-number-notes-etc-to-an-existing-contact-android-2-1).

I want to :
1. Find a specific contact.
2. When found, insert specific notes

I'm doing it in the following way:

```
Cursor contacts = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);

while(contacts.moveToNext()){

      Log.d("TC", "Found : " + name);

      int rid = contacts.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID);
      int rawContactID = contacts.getInt(rid);

      int nameIdx = contacts.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME);
      String name = contacts.getString(nameIdx);

      if <Some condition>{
            ContentValues contentValues =  new ContentValues();
            contentValues.put(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, rawContactID);
            contentValues.put(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Note.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);
            contentValues.put(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Note.NOTE, "Bazzinga !");
            int stat = getContentResolver().update(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, contentValues, null , null);
            Log.d("TC", "Update returned : " + stat);
      }

}
```

I get no errors. But the contact doesn't get updated :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace the

```
getContentResolver().update(...)
```

with

```
getContentResolver().insert( Data.CONTENT_URI, contentValues );
```

Also you should have a where statement in the Data.CONTENT_URI query. Because Data table can have multiple entries with same raw_contact_id. You can use "Data.MIMETYPE = StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE".

Comment: On some review of the documentation, I got that I need to insert a row in the Data table for the RawContact. I'll try this !