# What is replacement for Contacts.People.NOTES?

Tags: android, contacts, contactscontract, replace

This is sort of out of curiosity question. Reading through Pro Android 3 book and I came upon [Contacts.People.NOTES](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Contacts.PeopleColumns.html#NOTES). Since People is inner class of [Contacts](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Contacts.html) class which been deprecated and replaced by [ContactsContract](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.html) I'm looking for NOTES constant replacement. Is there anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two similar Stack Overflow questions that will have you resolve this issue:

- [Adding Notes to Existing Contacts](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5327739/1101070)
- [Add datas to an existing contact](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3100506/1101070)

But to answer your question, the field you're looking for is most likely:

```
ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Note.NOTE
```

Comment: Here is direct link to API [ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Note.NOTE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Note.html#NOTE) little buried in the documentation